# Algorithm to remove duplicate characters in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I am working a [program](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/reduced-string) that states that

There is a string, consisting of  lowercase English alphabetic letters. In one operation, we can delete any pair of adjacent letters with same value.

For example, string "aabcc" would become either "aab" or "bcc" after operation.

The result should reduced  as much as possible. To do this, we have to repeat the above operation as many times as it can be performed.

Example:

```
case 1:

Input - aaabccddd
Output - abd
```

Here the sequence of operations are as follows:

```
aaabccddd → abccddd
abccddd → abddd
abddd → abd
```

You can refer to above link for more details.

I tried to use List to solve the problem but I see it is not the right approach:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String data = scan.next();
        scan.close();
        
        String[] dataArr = data.split("");
        
        List<String> elements = Arrays.asList(data.split(""));
        
        for(int i=0; i< elements.size()-1; i++) {
            if(elements.get(i).equals(elements.get(i+1))) {
                elements.remove(i);
                elements.remove(i+1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(elements);
    }
}
```

I get error as : `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

Please help me on what is the right way to solve this problem.

Comment: The list produced by [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) does not support the `remove` operation. (It only wraps the array you initialise it with, and arrays cannot be resized.) You could use a [`java.util.ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't iterate the list forwards if you are removing from it: you'll miss out elements, or process elements you didn't expect to.

Comment: A better way to do this is to add the stuff you're not deleting to a new string. Cut out the list stuff.

Comment: you could pass the list to the ArrayList copy constructor like `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(data.split("")));` but my guess is that you would then recieve a `ConcurrentModificationException` as removing elements from a list while iterating over it in a for loop is not supported.

Comment: @911DidBush using an iterative loop, but using the index, this is acceptable

Comment: Tip: Asking help for solving training challenges actually defeats its learning purpose

Comment: Repeating the operation as many times as possible, does that mean that `abccb` could become `a`? `abccb` -> `abb` -> `a`.

Comment: @amitosh, that is right for a great part. On the other hand, you don’t learn much from trying and getting stuck and having to give up.

Comment: @OleV.V., yes it is repeated operation. Answer by Andy solves the base case, I will work on the remaining part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that we’re already helping too much and the asker has accpeted an answer, allow me to offer my solution:

```
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(input.length());
    for (int ix = 0; ix < input.length(); ix++) {
        char ch = input.charAt(ix);
        if (endsWith(ch, result)) {
            removeLastChar(result);
        } else {
            result.append(ch);
        }
    }
    String output = result.toString();
```

I am doing everything in one pass, and I don’t think it is getting too complicated (though it’s not the solution with fewest lines of code).

I am using two auxiliary methods:

```
private static boolean endsWith(char ch, StringBuilder buf) {
    return buf.length() > 0 && buf.charAt(buf.length() - 1) == ch;
}

private static void removeLastChar(StringBuilder buf) {
    buf.setLength(buf.length() - 1);
}
```

Comment: This actually should be the correct answer. This is the correct O(N) approach as asked! The accepted answer fails on `baab`

Answer (score 7):

[`Arrays#asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) creates **unmodifiable** list, check the docs:

> Returns a **fixed-size** list backed by the specified array.

You can't remove elements from it. Try:

```
List<String> elements = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(data.split("")));
```

Comment: Just nitpicking, fixed-size and unmodifiable is not the same. You can replace elements in the fixed-size list, thus modifying it. The important point here is, as you said, you cannot delete any elements from it.

Answer (score 6):

[Maroun Maroun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42070934/3788176) describes the specific reason for the exception in your code.

An easier solution than splitting to a list is to iterate through the string character-wise:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int i = 0;
while (i < str.length()) {
  if (i + 1 < str.length() && str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i + 1)) {
    i += 2;
  } else {
    sb.append(str.charAt(i));
    i += 1;
  }
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: @amitosh so put it in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Along with the fix by @MarounMaroun you need to be careful when deleting values from the list you're iterating over.

```
for(int i=0; i< elements.size()-1; i++) {
    if(elements.get(i).equals(elements.get(i+1))) {
        elements.remove(i);
        elements.remove(i+1); // not the index you think it is 
    }
}
```

Because you remove index `i` first, the element you thought was at `i+1` is now shifted back to `i`. As a rule of thumb, its easier to delete items further down the list before ones that are closer to the beginning. You could write:

```
for(int i=0; i< elements.size()-1; i++) {
    if(elements.get(i).equals(elements.get(i+1))) {
        elements.remove(i+1);
        elements.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Or you could write:

```
for(int i=0; i< elements.size()-1; i++) {
    if(elements.get(i).equals(elements.get(i+1))) {
        elements.remove(i);
        elements.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it (as I solved the question last time) is to use Regex

```
// Somehow read input and store it in a String input
String regex = "(.)\\1";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    input = m.replaceAll("");
    m = r.matcher(input);
}
// check length, do other things and print
```

Thanks @OleV.V. for pointing the string escaping mistake

Comment: Oops: you need to escape the backslash, as in `"(.)\\1"`. Your program as written compiles and runs with no sign of error, only doesn’t remove any characters.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank's for pointing out, I wrote this code from recall, and now that I use so much Python and JS ... Forgetting escaping things